# Abort IBAction on "if statement error"

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, ibaction, abort

i'm trying to make my first user-registration. The registration will be made by 4 textfields that need to be edited by the user and saved after pushing a button (IBAction). This IBAction needs to be aborted when 1 field is empty. A warning text will be shown to the user and he/she will need to correct the problem before proceeding to save the textdata to a parse server/

I've connected my 4 Uitextfields to the .m script AND i think i've written a good if statement. But how can I stop my script after the warning text?

CODE .M :

```
- (IBAction)REGISTERNEWUSER:(id)sender
{

    //DEFINE STRINGS FOR MODULE
    NSString *NICKNAME = Nickname.text;
    NSString *USERNAME = Username.text;
    NSString *PASSWORD = Password.text;
    NSString *EMAIL = Email.text;
    NSString *ERRORREGISTRATION = @"Please fill up all fields above before proceeding with the  registration...";

    //CHECK IF ALL REGISTRATION FIELDS ARE FILLED
    if ([Nickname.text length] > 0 || [Username.text length] > 0 || [Password.text length] > 0 || [Email.text length] > 0 )
    {
    }
    ErrorRegistration.text = ERRORREGISTRATION;

    //
    // METHODE NEEDS TO STOP HERE
    // BUT AT MOMENT CONTINUES TO SEND DATA TO PARSE
    //
    {

    }


    //SEND DATA TO PARSE SERVER
    PFObject *User = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"USER"];
    [User setValue:NICKNAME forKey:@"Nickname"];
    [User setValue:USERNAME forKey:@"Username"];
    [User setValue:PASSWORD forKey:@"Password"];
    [User setValue:EMAIL forKey:@"Email"];
    [User save];
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided.
Kind Regards,
Lien.

Comment: Add a `return` statement where you want to exit the method (it's not a "script").

Comment: I am new to this "return statement". Does the return statement need to point to somewere or will it automatically return to "before the button pressed"? Thank you for correcting me on the methode vs script words. Your right (blush) I will change it in my coding.

Comment: If you don't know what the `return` statement does then please stop work on an iOS app and please spend some time learning the basics of Objective-C (and C). It will be time well spent. You can't write an app if you don't understand the basics of the programming language. I mean this as a helpful comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
if ([Nickname.text length] == 0 || [Username.text length] == 0 || [Password.text length] == 0 || [Email.text length] == 0 ) {
    // Not all fields are entered
    ErrorRegistration.text = ERRORREGISTRATION;
} else {
    // All fields are entered
    //SEND DATA TO PARSE SERVER
    PFObject *User = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"USER"];
    [User setValue:NICKNAME forKey:@"Nickname"];
    [User setValue:USERNAME forKey:@"Username"];
    [User setValue:PASSWORD forKey:@"Password"];
    [User setValue:EMAIL forKey:@"Email"];
    [User save];
}
```

BTW - Fix your caps lock key. Method and variable names should use camelCase (beginning with a lowercase letter). Class names should use CamelCase (begging with an uppercase letter).

```
if ([nickname.text length] == 0 || [username.text length] == 0 || [password.text length] == 0 || [email.text length] == 0 ) {
    // Not all fields are entered
    errorRegistration.text = @"Please fill up all fields above before proceeding with the  registration...";
} else {
    // All fields are entered
    //SEND DATA TO PARSE SERVER
    PFObject *user = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"USER"];
    [user setValue:nickname.text forKey:@"Nickname"];
    [user setValue:username.text forKey:@"Username"];
    [user setValue:password.text forKey:@"Password"];
    [user setValue:email.text forKey:@"Email"];
    [user save];
}
```

No need for all of the extra variables in this case.

Comment: Thanks, your coding worked like a charm. :) Sorry for the caps in the variables.   Its a way i've been using for some time and i've adapted to it. Is using your mentioned CAPS usage obligatory,could it give problems on long term or is it just a standard? Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: THe naming convention I mentioned certainly isn't required. However, it is a standard used by many programmers in Objective-C, Java, and other languages. Using a common standard makes your code easier to read by others. If you ever work with other developers it is important that the team uses the same coding standards to make things easier. If it will always be just you and your own code then do what you want. But even then I'd recommend following the common conventions.